# Pygame Platformer Sprite Collisions only working in one way

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I am currently working on a simple school project, where I am coding a Platformer. My Problem is, that the collisions between my player and my platform(s) are checked one after another, so if I check the X Collision first, the Collisions on the sides of the Platforms work completly fine, but as soon as I move, my character will be teleported to the side of the platform, because the gravity pulls me in the platform and i am moving left or right, so the program thinks I am hitting a platform from the side and sets the player rect onto the side of the platform. The same thing happens if I check for X Collision first, but with the Collisions on the sides of the platforms not working.

Is there a way of around it, so my collisions are working like in a Mario-like Game? I tried several things and removed the calculation with Friction and Acceleration for smooth movement, but nothing seems to work for me.

Here is my full code:

```
import random
import os

WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60
TITLE = "Game"

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder,"textures")

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
DARKGREY = (40, 40, 40)
LIGHTGREY = (100, 100, 100)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.5

PGROUND = "dirtplatform.png"
PBLOCK = "dirt.png"

PLATFORM_LIST = [(0, HEIGHT - 64, PGROUND),
                 (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, PBLOCK),
                 (WIDTH / 4, HEIGHT / 4, PBLOCK)]

vec = pygame.math.Vector2

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder,"player.png")).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey((130,255,230))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2)
        self.vel = vec(0,0)

    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y += 1
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
        self.rect.y -= 1
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = -20

    def collision(self, direction):
        if direction == 'x':
           hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
           if hits:
                print("Hit x")
                if self.vel.x > 0:
                    self.rect.right = hits[0].rect.left
                if self.vel.x < 0: 
                    self.rect.left  = hits[0].rect.right   
                self.vel.x = 0
        if direction == 'y':
            hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
            if hits:
                print("Hit y")
                if self.vel.y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = hits[0].rect.top 
                if self.vel.y < 0: 
                    self.rect.top= hits[0].rect.bottom
                self.vel.y = 0

    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0,PLAYER_GRAV)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.vel.x = -5
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.vel.x = 5

        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.vel.x
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.vel.y

        self.collision('x')
        self.collision('y')



        print("vel",self.vel)
        print("rectX",self.rect.x)
        print("rectY",self.rect.y)

        self.vel.y = self.vel.y + PLAYER_GRAV

        self.vel.x = 0

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder,image)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True


    def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
        for plat in PLATFORM_LIST:
            p = Platform(*plat)
            self.all_sprites.add(p)
            self.platforms.add(p)
        self.run()

    def run(self):       
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def collision(self):
        if self.player.vel.y > 0 and pygame:
            hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
            if hits:
                self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
                self.player.vel.y = 0

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.player.rect.right >= WIDTH-100:
            self.player.rect.x = WIDTH - 110
            for plat in self.platforms:
                plat.rect.right -= abs(self.player.vel.x)

        if self.player.rect.left <= 100:
            self.player.rect.x = 110
            for plat in self.platforms:
                plat.rect.right += abs(self.player.vel.x)

    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.jump()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass

    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass

g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while g.running:
    g.new()
    g.show_go_screen

pygame.quit()
```

Note: dirtplatform.png represents the ground of the game and dirt.png is a block, which the player should be able to jump on

Comment: I did put it in class Player()??

Comment: Sorry, somehow slipped through and I didn't recheck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collisions are hard, there doesn't seem to be any perfect way of doing it, and every time i do it, it changes everytime. Saying that, this seems to work very well with the 2 mins of testing i just did:

```
def collision(self):
    for platform in self.game.platforms: #check every platform
        if self.rect.colliderect(platform.rect): #if the two rects collided
            if self.rect.right <= platform.rect.left + self.vel.x:
                self.rect.right = platform.rect.left   
                self.vel.x = 0
            if self.rect.left >= platform.rect.right + self.vel.x:
                self.rect.left = platform.rect.right   
                self.vel.x = 0 
            if self.rect.bottom <= platform.rect.top + self.vel.y:
                self.rect.bottom = platform.rect.top  
                self.vel.y = 0  
            if self.rect.top >= platform.rect.bottom + self.vel.y:
                self.rect.top = platform.rect.bottom 
                self.vel.y = 0
```

Comment: Thanks alot, the top collision now works completly fine and the player movement aswell, but the side and top collision don't work at all for me. Did they work in your testing?

Comment: Didn't actually test the sides. It should be just reversing the inequality signs and it will work. Ill definitely test it and sort it out tho

Comment: @Hochspannungswerk ve tested it and found the problem, because velocity can be negative, i should be adding the negative velocity instead of subtracting it which makes a double negaitive and basically breaks it. Also got rid of the break so you can collide with 2 platforms at same time. may start getting slow once you have heaps of them. But this works now

Comment: Thanks!! Now works completely fine. Have a nice day